# How to get vocabulary size of word2vec?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, nlp, word2vec, apache-spark-ml

I have a pretrained word2vec model in pyspark and I would like to know how big is its vocabulary (and perhaps get a list of words in the vocabulary).
Is this possible? I would guess it has to be stored somewhere since it can predict for new data, but I couldn't find a clear answer in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.Word2Vec.html).

I tried `w2v_model.getVectors().count()` but the result (*970*) seem too small for my use case. In case it may be relevant, I'm using short-text data and my dataset has tens of millions of messages each having from 10 to 30/40 words. I am using `min_count=50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why you doubt the result of `.getVectors().count()`, which gives the desired result indeed, as shown in the [documentation link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.Word2Vec.html) you have provided yourself.

Here is the example posted there, with a vocabulary of just three (3) tokens - `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec

sent = ("a b " * 100 + "a c " * 10).split(" ") # 3-token vocabulary
doc = spark.createDataFrame([(sent,), (sent,)], ["sentence"])
word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=5, seed=42, inputCol="sentence", outputCol="model")
model = word2Vec.fit(doc)
```

So, unsurprisingly, it is

```
model.getVectors().count()
# 3
```

and asking for the vectors themselves

```
model.getVectors().show()
```

gives

```
+----+--------------------+
|word|              vector|
+----+--------------------+
|   a|[0.09511678665876...|
|   b|[-1.2028766870498...|
|   c|[0.30153277516365...|
+----+--------------------+
```

In your case, with `min_count=50`, every word that appears less than 50 times in your corpus will not be represented; reducing this number will result in more vectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was surprised at first but now I realised it is not so exceptional after all. I just needed external confirmation maybe :)